# Oracle WebLogic Server is "Stopped" and yet I can't start it in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

When I open the Servers view in Eclipse (Galileo), I have a localhost instance of WLS with a "[Stopped]" indicator on it.  When I attempt to start the supposedly stopped instance, I get these errors:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
```

The "Address already in use" part clued me in that WLS was already running.

How can I stop/view the output of the currently running instance?

I normally run WLS through the command line (Windows) separately but I'm starting to fiddle around with running WLS right inside of Eclipse.

I've been searching for a good guide on setting Eclipse up to interact with WLS but haven't found one yet.  If any of you can recommend one I would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the message you see means that java debugger cannot bind to the specified port, and not (yet) that weblogic cannot bind to its listen address.
This, can be due to an existing running weblogic instance (running with debugger enabled and on the same port) as you say, but may also mean that another Java program has been started with JDWP enabled on the same port.

So in the second case, please search if there is such a process (netstat -a will help) or just change debugger port you are trying to start weblogic with

If instead you really have a running weblogic instance, there are three cases:
1) it is a windows service (strange that you run weblogic as a service with JDWP activated), thus you can search and stop it through windows services ui
2) you started it through the command line, but in this case you would easily find the command line window you used to start it.
3) it is started by eclipse and you cannot see it for any reason, which is quite strange since it means that eclipse would have started two weblogic instances and one is failing. You can search in eclipse console view if you find a running instance (many consoles can be used at the same time). IF you don't find it just try to quit eclipse, WLS must die together with eclipse and you will see it in weblogic logs or through WLS process disappearing from task manager.

Are you using Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse for running weblogic there? If yes I think this is a good introduction:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/11/oepe11g/introeclipseide.htm

Comment: +1 - good points - I think you've just about covered everything here so I'm going to award you the correct answer

Comment: +1 for netstat -a. I'd renamed my server and my existing shutdown script was bombing out after failing to resolve the hostname. I had an instance running that I didn't think was.